# How do i perform multiple actions that depends on a policy?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have two action with the same route path and I need to perform each action depending on user's permissions.
The code i wrote doesn't work. it says: `AmbiguousActionException: Multiple actions matched.`
Here are actions:

```
    [HttpPost("info"), Authorize("only-boxer")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> EditProfile([FromBody]BoxerProfileInfoEditModel model)
    {
        // do one thing...
    }
    [HttpPost("info"), Authorize("only-manager")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> EditProfile([FromBody]ManagerProfileInfoEditModel model)
    {
        // do another thing...
    }
```

And that's how i register policies:

```
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("only-boxer", policy =>
            {
                policy.RequireRole("boxer");
            });
            options.AddPolicy("only-manager", policy =>
            {
                policy.RequireRole("manager", "promoter");
            });
        });
```

Should i check the permissions in one action and extract data manually or there's more neat way?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this solution is right and fit, but
[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1#understanding-iactionconstraint) i knew about Action Constraints and wrote own one

```
public class RoleAttribute : Attribute, IActionConstraint
{
    public int Order => 0;

    private string[] _roles;

    public RoleAttribute(params string[] roles)
    {
        _roles = roles;
    }

    public bool Accept(ActionConstraintContext context)
    {
        var user = context.RouteContext.HttpContext.User;
        var role = user.FindFirst("role-name").Value;
        return _roles.Contains(role);
    }
}
```

So, this is working, now.

```
    [HttpPost("info"), Authorize, Role("boxer")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> EditProfile([FromBody]BoxerProfileInfoEditModel model)
    {
        // do one thing...
    }
    [HttpPost("info"), Authorize, Role("manager", "promoter")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> EditProfile([FromBody]ManagerProfileInfoEditModel model)
    {
        // do another thing...
    }
```

I appreciate if you'd share your thoughts about this or another solution to perform that.